# Como hacer un delay después de cargar la página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Estoy intentando esto

```
function m(){
$('.l').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
}
$(window).load(m);
```

pero ahora quiero que haga un delay de 3 segundos después de que la pagina cargue

intente con `setTimeout()` pero hace otra cosa

`setTimeout(($(window).load(m)), 3000);`

intente con `delay`

`$(window).load(m).delay(3000);`

también con `sleep`

```
function m(){
sleep(3000);
    $('.l').animate({opacity:"0"},1000);
    }
```

Comment: si estas usando jquery `load()` es para cargar contenido. Si buscas ejecutar una funcion cuando la pagina carga, prueba `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A la función **[`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** te faltaría indicarle el parámetro `queue: false`. Según la documentación:

> **queue (default: true)** Un booleano indicando si colocar la animación en la cola de efectos. Si es **falso**, la animación empezará automáticamente.

Ejemplo:

```js
function m(){
  $('.l').animate({opacity:"0"}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
}

setTimeout(function() {    
    m();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.l{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="l"></div>
```